# Computer Turn, Wait and delay in Android 2.2

Tags: android

I am making a Poker game in Android, I have made some `TextViews` and `ImageViews` to show on the cards of player and computer and the Community cards..

Now the problem is that when a player takes its turn after that it calls a method of call_computer and all the implementation of the computer executes but there is no delay between the player and computer turn.

So a player takes its turn and just after that a card is displayed. What I want is after the player turn, the computer should wait for a while and then it would display a text:

> "Computer Selects Check/Fold/Raise"

and then according to the action selected the card should be displayed....

I have called a `call_computer` function just after the player's turn and action performed.. and I put that method in a new thread and put a sleep of 5 sec, but still no success...

Comment: show some animation in between ... by the way there are sisters on this site too .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a call to `postDelayed(Runnable, int)`:

```
long DELAY_IN_MSEC = 1000; // 1s
postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // call_computer();
    }
}, DELAY_IN_MSEC);
```